# Part of custom Android view for IME being cut off?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, ime

I'm working on an IME for Android and for that purpose I've created a custom view.

I'm setting up the view in an XML file like this:

```
<com.paldepind.mykeyboard.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
/>
```

I want the view to be 40% the height of the screen. Thus in my custom view I'm overriding the `onMeasure` method that views have:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = (int) (View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) * .4);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,
                         View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height,
                         View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

When viewed on the phone the view correctly begins 60% down on the screen – but it is then being cut off a little further down as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Android screenshot]

If I change the `.4` in my code above to just `1` the view does however fill up the entire screen as expected. It seems that the lower the number is, the more of the view is being cut off.

I really can't figure out why this wouldn't work. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `onMeasure` method was for some reason begin called twice. The first time the `heightMeasureSpec` parameter was equal to the screen size and the second time the parameter was set to the before set height of the view. Thus the view ended up being only 40% off 40% of the screen size.

I have fixed the issue by getting the screen size specifically in the `onMeasure` method call:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = (int) (size.y * .4);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,
                         View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the keyboardview inside a relative layout. Maybe can solve it.